# .ShowDialog not creating modal form

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, messagebox, showdialog

Using C# .Net 4

My application loads an audio file at startup, in the event that the path to the audio file is invalid, we warn the user. I am making improvements which allows the user to locate the file, remove the association, or proceed unchanged.

Previously I was using the MessageBox to do this, and it worked great, however the need for custom buttons means that I had to create the custom dialog.

When I call this custom dialog it is not preventing actions on the main form, you can still click menus, buttons, drag and drop things, etc... Where the MessageBox does not allow interaction with the main form until you clicked OK or Cancel to dismiss the dialog. I have left both in the following method for demonstration.

So, calling the MessageBox.Show halts all actions to the main form, calling my custom form with .ShowDialog() does not, what am I doing wrong ?

```
private void PopulateWaveformAudio()
    {
        if (_sequence.GetAllMedia().Any())
        {
            IMediaModuleInstance media = _sequence.GetAllMedia().First();
            Audio audio = media as Audio;
            toolStripMenuItem_removeAudio.Enabled = true;
            if (audio.MediaExists)
            {
                TimelineControl.Audio = audio;
                toolStripButton_AssociateAudio.ToolTipText = string.Format("Associated Audio: {0}",
                    Path.GetFileName(audio.MediaFilePath));
            }
            else
            {
                InvalidAudioPathDialog result = new InvalidAudioPathDialog(audio.MediaFilePath);
                result.ShowDialog();

                switch(result.InvalidAudioDialogResult)
                {
                    case InvalidAudioDialogResult.KeepAudio:
                        break;
                    case InvalidAudioDialogResult.RemoveAudio:
                        break;
                    case InvalidAudioDialogResult.LocateAudio:
                        break;

                }

                string message = String.Format("Audio file not found on the path:\n\n {0}\n\nPlease Check your settings/path.",
                    audio.MediaFilePath);
                Logging.Warn(message);
                MessageBox.Show(message, @"Missing audio file",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that this method runs on a worker thread.  Double-check with the debugger's Debug + Windows + Threads window.  That's very dangerous, beyond it not being modal, use BeginInvoke() to get the dialog displayed on the UI thread.  If that's not the case then be sure to use the ShowDialog(owner) overload so it doesn't have to find an owner by itself.

Comment: Please update your question with more detail on how you call this function. I've never seen `ShowDialog` behave the way you describe it so I can't think of any other reason for your problem than Hans Passant's suggestion.

Comment: @HansPassant Your crystal ball seems extremely accurate. Can it predict the lottery numbers for me?

Comment: @HansPassant This was the case, I have never ran into this before, you saved my day!